# onReset causes RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: typescript, forms, react-redux, react-bootstrap, formik

In my React Redux application, I use react-bootstrap(v^1.6.0) with Formik(v2.2.6) to build a filters form.

Everything works fine except reset handling. After I click my reset button,  I get

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
resetForm
src/Formik.tsx:347
  344 |   }
  345 | }, [validateOnMount, validateFormWithHighPriority]);
  346 | 
> 347 | const resetForm = React.useCallback(
      | ^  348 |   (nextState?: Partial<FormikState<Values>>) => {
  349 |     const values =
  350 |       nextState && nextState.values
View compiled
onResetAction [as onReset]
src/use-cases/schools-page/declarations-page/components/DeclarationsFilter.tsx:42
  39 | }
  40 | 
  41 | const onResetAction = (values: FilterValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FilterValues>) => {
> 42 |   helpers.resetForm()
     | ^  43 |   onFilterChange({})
  44 | }
  45 |
```

My code below

```
import React from 'react'
import { Declaration } from 'store/declarations/reducer'
import { DeclarationsFilters } from 'use-cases/schools-page/declarations-page/types'
import { Button, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { uniq } from 'lodash'
import { Formik, FormikHelpers } from 'formik'

type Props = {
  filters: DeclarationsFilters
  allDeclarations: Declaration[]
  onFilterChange: (filters: DeclarationsFilters) => void
}

type FilterValues = {
  surname: string
  classNumber: string
  className: string
}

const all = 'wszystkie'

export const DeclarationsFilter: React.FC<Props> = ({ filters, allDeclarations, onFilterChange }): JSX.Element => {
  const allClasses = uniq(allDeclarations.map((declaration) => declaration.classNumber))
  const allClassNames = uniq(allDeclarations.map((declaration) => declaration.className))

  const onSearch = (values: FilterValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FilterValues>) => {
    helpers.setSubmitting(true)
    const changedFilters: DeclarationsFilters = {
      surname: values.surname,
      selectedClass: values.classNumber === all ? undefined : parseInt(values.classNumber, 10),
      selectedClassName: values.className === all ? undefined : values.className
    }
    onFilterChange(changedFilters)
    helpers.setSubmitting(false)
  }

  const onResetAction = (values: FilterValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FilterValues>) => {
    helpers.resetForm()
    onFilterChange({})
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        classNumber: filters.selectedClass?.toString() || all,
        className: filters.selectedClassName || all,
        surname: filters.surname || ''
      }}
      onSubmit={onSearch}
      onReset={onResetAction}
    >
      {({ handleSubmit, isSubmitting, handleChange, handleBlur, values, handleReset }) => (
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={handleReset}>
          <Form.Row>
            <Col>
              <Form.Group controlId="declarationsFilter.surname">
                <Form.Label>Nazwisko</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="..."
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  name="surname"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.surname}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Form.Group controlId="declarationsFilter.classNumber">
                <Form.Label>Klasa:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  as="select"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  name="classNumber"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.classNumber}
                >
                  <option>{all}</option>
                  {allClasses.map((classNumber) => (
                    <option>{classNumber}</option>
                  ))}
                </Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Form.Group controlId="declarationsFilter.className">
                <Form.Label>Nazwa klasy:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  as="select"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  name="className"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.className}
                >
                  <option>{all}</option>
                  {allClassNames.map((classNumber) => (
                    <option>{classNumber}</option>
                  ))}
                </Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
            </Col>
          </Form.Row>
          <Form.Row>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Filtruj
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" type="reset">
              Resetuj
            </Button>
          </Form.Row>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

Method 'onFilterChange' does nothing for now. It will update redux store in the future.

Does anybody understand this behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have created an infinite loop:

1. Click reset
2. Trigger Formik `onReset`, which calls `onResetAction`
3. `onResetAction` calls `helper.resetForm()`
4. ... which imperatively resets the form, which
5. which Triggers Formik `onReset` and around you go for ever

To fix it, don't call `resetForm` from `onReset`. If you want to wire up a reset button, you can just hook your `onResetAction` directly to the `onClick` handler of an ordinary (i.e. not 'reset') button.